# tensor dot product in keras

Tags: python, keras, tensor, dot-product

I am new to keras, and got some problems understanding the keras.layers.Dot() layer.

I am trying to calculate a dot product of two vectors.

```py
from keras.layers import Input, Dot
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

x1 = Input(shape=(4,))
x2 = Input(shape=(4,))
y1 = Dot(axes=1)([x1,x2])
model = Model(inputs=[x1, x2], outputs=y1)

a1 = np.arange(4)
a2=np.arange(4)
model.predict([a1,a2])
```

I expect the output to be 14=0+1^2+2^2+3^2. However, I got error message like below:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_46 to have shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I tried to run `model.get_config()`, and below is the corresponding information about the graph of the model. As you can see input_46 is x1, and input_47 is x2.

```
{'name': 'model_19',
 'layers': [{'name': 'input_46',
   'class_name': 'InputLayer',
   'config': {'batch_input_shape': (None, 4),
    'dtype': 'float32',
    'sparse': False,
    'name': 'input_46'},
   'inbound_nodes': []},
  {'name': 'input_47',
   'class_name': 'InputLayer',
   'config': {'batch_input_shape': (None, 4),
    'dtype': 'float32',
    'sparse': False,
    'name': 'input_47'},
   'inbound_nodes': []},
  {'name': 'dot_20',
   'class_name': 'Dot',
   'config': {'name': 'dot_20',
    'trainable': True,
    'axes': 1,
    'normalize': False},
   'inbound_nodes': [[['input_46', 0, 0, {}], ['input_47', 0, 0, {}]]]}],
 'input_layers': [['input_46', 0, 0], ['input_47', 0, 0]],
 'output_layers': [['dot_20', 0, 0]]}
```

Is there anything I didn't do right? Thanks!

## UPDATE

The following code worked:

```py
x1 = Input(shape=(4,))
x2 = Input(shape=(4,))
y1 = Dot(axes=1)([x1,x2])
model = Model(inputs=[x1, x2], outputs=y1)
a1 = np.arange(4).reshape(1,4)
a2=np.arange(4).reshape(1,4)
model.predict([a1,a2])
```

or

```py
from keras.layers import Input, Dot
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

x1 = Input(shape=(4,))
x2 = Input(shape=(4,))
y1 = Dot(axes=1)([x1,x2])
model = Model(inputs=[x1, x2], outputs=y1)

a1 = np.arange(4)
a2=np.arange(4)
model.predict([[a1],[a2]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras waits for get a batch of your inputs. like a vector of size N*4 if you have N inputs of the dimension 4. So if you want to send a single vector, it shoul dbe in the dimension of 1*4 and not 4. 
So you have two choices:

1. Change the

   a1 = np.arange(4)
   a2=np.arange(4)

To

```
a1 = np.arange(1,4)
a2=np.arange(1,4)
```

2. or Try `model.predict([[a1],[a2]])` . Should solve your issue.